# Package ggvoronoi in latest R (4.2.1) in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS failing to install

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, package

I have been successfully using the package `ggvoronoi` even a few weeks ago in R (3+). Until then all of a sudden `R` started to tell me:

```
> library(ggvoronoi)
Error in library(ggvoronoi) : there is no package called ‘ggvoronoi’
```

Okay, then I tried to install the package, but then getting the following error:

```
> install.packages("ggvoronoi")
Installing package into ‘/home/pratikmullick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggvoronoi’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

Finally I updated the R to 4.2.1. This is my `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1 tools_4.2.1
```

But even then the problem with installing `ggvoronoi` did not solve:

```
> install.packages('ggvoronoi')
Installing package into ‘/home/pratikmullick/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggvoronoi’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can try installing it from the github `remotes::install_github("garretrc/ggvoronoi", dependencies = TRUE, build_opts = c("--no-resave-data"))`

Comment: I did this. But it still does not work :(

Comment: I just tried @MohanGovindasamy's suggestion, and it worked for me.  It's probably a better approach than my answer to your other question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73442589/2554330.

Comment: Of course, package `ggvoronoi` used to work perfect for my case, until it was removed from CRAN :(