# How to plot tiles obtained from deldir tesselation using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, voronoi, deldir

Now that `ggvoronoi` package is not working anymore in `R`, I am using `deldir` to plot voronoi cells clipped by the convex hull for a bunch of points in the following way:

```
library(deldir)
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50)
y <- runif(50)

tesselation <- deldir(x, y)
tiles <- tile.list(tesselation)

s <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 3000)
circle <- list(x = 0.5 * (1 + cos(s)),
               y = 0.5 * (1 + sin(s)))

plot(tiles, pch = 19,
     col.pts = "white",
     border = "white",
     fillcol = hcl.colors(50, "viridis"),
     clipp = circle)
```

[image]

I want to create a gradient plot for the tiles according to the area of the tiles. Or in some way to import `tiles` in `ggplot` and then use the functionalities like `scale_fill_gradientn` to achieve my goal. Can you please help me?

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible?  I think you just need to add the construction of the `points` and `con.hull` variables and the `library()` calls for the functions you used.

Comment: I have added them as you requested. Thanks for your help :) Actually I need to color the cells according to `points$density_voronoi`, which is just 1/area for each cell.

Comment: That's not reproducible without a lot of work.  Follow the suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2554330 if you want someone to help you.

Comment: I apologize. I have now summarized the problem with a simple example. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your nice reproducible example.

As far as I know, `ggplot2` doesn't support clipping polygons directly.  There are some workarounds:  drawing a big polygon on top of them to obscure the parts you don't want to see, or clipping the polygons before you draw them using some other package, or working "down a level" with the `grid` package to modify the final plot.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51715907/2554330) has answers that explore a couple of those methods.  Here, I'm just going to concentrate on drawing the Voronoi cells and not attempt the clipping.

The main issue is extracting the cells and their color from the `tiles` object.  It's a list, with one entry per cell.  If you look at `str(tiles[[1]])` you'll see something like this:

```
List of 6
 $ ptNum: int 1
 $ pt   : Named num [1:2] 0.266 0.478
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "x" "y"
 $ x    : num [1:8] 0.386 0.365 0.317 0.128 0.141 ...
 $ y    : num [1:8] 0.638 0.656 0.67 0.642 0.509 ...
 $ bp   : logi [1:8] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ area : num 0.0402
 - attr(*, "ncomp")= num 1
```

The boundary of the cell is in the polygon defined by the `x` and `y` components.

So here's one way to do what you want (except for the clipping):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(deldir)

set.seed(1)
x <- runif(50)
y <- runif(50)

tesselation <- deldir(x, y)
tiles <- tile.list(tesselation)

s <- seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 3000)
circle <- list(x = 0.5 * (1 + cos(s)),
               y = 0.5 * (1 + sin(s)))

points <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
colors <- hcl.colors(50, "viridis")

g <- ggplot(points, aes(x = x, y = y))
for (i in 1:50)
  g <- g + geom_polygon(data = data.frame(x = tiles[[i]]$x,
                                          y = tiles[[i]]$y,
                                          density = 1/tiles[[i]]$area), 
                        aes(fill = density))
g <- g + geom_point(col = "white")
g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I would still need to figure out how to do perform the clipping part, which is extremely essential for my case.

Comment: If you try the `ggvoronoi` package from Github now, it should work.